# Create Calendar Item WIth SOAP / Exchange EWS

Tags: asp.net, soap, exchangewebservices

I want to create an appointment on a Public Calendar in Exchange 2010 using an ASP.Net 4.5 WebForm and C#.  I've found some resources on EWS and SOAP, but I don't know how to get started creating it.  I've never worked with XML files before and don't know how to send them to the Exchange server from my ASP.Net app.

Are there any simple examples of this?

Comment: For the SOAP services, there's nothing terribly special about them. See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a huge knowledge of SOAP/XML when using the EWS Managed API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633709(v=exchg.80).aspx

The link above provides example of how to create a link to the exchange service, as well as create and edit appointments.

It's a good starting block.